# Permalinks with url parameters

Tags: html, .htaccess, url-parameters

I have a website in HTML CSS JS with Jquery Boostrap and Firebase. I do not have server-side code.
It's a platform with 20 articles.

With the URL parameter, I get the id of the article and dynamically replace thanks to DB the title, description, photo URL etc...
Here is a link :
https://visite-ton-ecole.fr/visiter.html?ec-nantes

Google does not SEO reference each of my URL parameters and so each of my articles. so I would like to rewrite the URL

from :
https://visite-ton-ecole.fr/visiter.html?ec-nantes

https://visite-ton-ecole.fr/visiter.html?my-school

to : https://visite-ton-ecole.fr/visiter/ec-nantes

https://visite-ton-ecole.fr/visiter/myschool

I've seen that it's called permalinks and that CDN like Wordpress does that automatically  when creating a new article.
I've seen that you can do that with the **.htaccess** :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?visiter/([^/d]+)/?$ visiter.html?$1 [L,QSA]
```

This **.htaccess** does work but when the page is fully loaded, it automatically redirect to my server root.

Is it good to use **.htaccess** ? or there is other solutions like server-side solutions ?

Comment: The target URL of your redirect starts with `visiter.html`, so I don’t see how what you have shown, could ever redirect you to the site route. There must be something else in play here.

Comment: Plus, if this was a redirect coming from the server side, it would not make sense that it “waits” for the page to fully load, before going elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the URL format, then the browser sees the URL in the new format and not the old format.

Your JavaScript, running in the browser, therefore also sees the URL in the new format and not the old format.

If your JavaScript is still trying to parse the URL as if it were the old format (i.e. get data from the query string) then it isn't going to find it.

You need to update your JavaScript so it can handle the new URL format.